# How to assign two different entities result set into single var variable using linq to sql c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using linq to sql.

Can I do like this ?

```
var lst = (somecondition) ? _db.Employees
                               .Where(a => a.EmployeeID.Equals(employeeId)) 
                          : _db.Departments
                               .Where(a => a.deptsID.Equals(deptId));
```

If my trying to do this it is throwing an error like this

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between `System.Linq.IQueryable<Employee>` and
>   `System.Linq.IQueryable<Department>`

Can any one give me suggestion to me.

Answer (score 1):

If those two entities don't share a common base class or a common interface, you cannot. Well technically you could put them both into a list of objects, but that's not what you want. Think about the program, how would you know if the list contains employees or departments and what would you do with them if they have nothing in common.

Answer (score 1):

They should be of the same type (this is why the compiler complains).
var is a syntactic sugar expression, so instead of writing something like:

```
ObservableCollection<SomeLongTypeHere> myCollection = new  
    ObservableCollection<SomeLongTypeHere> ();
```

you can write

```
var myCollection = new  
    ObservableCollection<SomeLongTypeHere> ();
```

And the compiler will know that `var` stands for `ObservableCollection<SomeLongTypeHere>`

What you try to do is like doing this:

```
var someVar = (condition) ? (int) 5 : (string) "some string";
```

The compiler can't set a type (is it an int? is it a string?), and hence, complains.

**Edit:**
Ok, first of all, i'm sorry, but your variable names s**ks ...
As a general rule, you want your variables to be meaningful, especially if you're asking people to read them and help you out with your problems (note, **your** problems, not theirs) ...
So, don't use things like :

```
var query = (from a in lst ...
```

use variable names that make sense, and are meaningful, for example:

```
var query = (from employee in employee_list ...
```

Now, `lst` is just as bad... have a `employees_list` or `departments_list` (or if you must: `empLst` or `dptLst`, but i highly suggest using long names that are meaningful. You'll spend more time reading it than writing it ... trust me on this).

Having said that, your `lst` is basically all the entries where employee ID is the same as that variable I assume.

You could either use 2 lists, and then depending on your condition use the proper list, or better yet, fork on the condition with an if/else and get the data.

You wouldn't mix entities into a var, because you can't really use them that way. Your GUI will depend on the properties of those objects, and hence it makes no sense to dynamically try to get a list of employees or departments into a general (`var`) in order to process them.

Without more details, I can't help further, but my first part answered the question you've posted: You can't do it that way (and if you could, you really shouldn't, because it'll be a hack at best and just cause grief down the road)

Comment: hi Noctis thanks for reply. var myCollection = new  
    ObservableCollection<object> ();  or var myCollection = new  
    ObservableCollection<entity> ();  what i have to declare here? little bit confusion here.

Comment: Neither, I was just explaining that `var` is there to make your life easier and type less. Your problem lies in the fact that the compiler can't know in advance which type he'll get.
You should either cast everything to `object` (very ugly), have both type inherit from the same base (so, using inheritance, they are both of the same base type, and could be valid in either case, but employees and departments don't seem to be related), or if you're using just the strings, use the strings. How are you going to use that `lst` of yours?

Comment: var lst = _db.employees.where(a => a.EmployeeId.Equals(employeeID)).AsQuerable(); 

var query = (from a in lst 
      join b in _db.XTable on a.employeeID equals b.EmployeeId into xb
             from xbs in xb.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
 // here i'll select columns
});  var lst = _db.departments.where(a => a.deptsID.Equals(deptId)).AsQuerable(); 

var query = (from a in lst 
      join b in _db.XTable on a.DeptID equals b.DeptId into xb
             from xbs in xb.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
 // here i'll select columns
});
i'm using in same method different situation

Comment: No worries, hope you'll take the variables names into consideration in the future. It'll make your life and others much easier. If you think you got your answer, don't forget to mark a question as answered (mine or others).

Answer (score 0):

This is useless, but you can :

```
object lst = (somecondition) ? (object)_db.Employees
                           .Where(a => a.EmployeeID.Equals(employeeId)) 
                      : _db.Departments
                           .Where(a => a.deptsID.Equals(deptId));
```

Both list will cast themselves to object. You will not be able to do anything with that variable, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the part to this:

```
object lst = (somecondition) ? (object)_db.Employees.**AsEnumerable()**
                           .Where(a => a.EmployeeID.Equals(employeeId)) 
                      : _db.Departments.**AsEnumerable()**
                           .Where(a => a.deptsID.Equals(deptId));
```

Notice this will change to "IEnumerable". LINQ-TO-OBJECT——**because not every LINQ can be converted to a standard SQL.**

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the two different types into a single varaible, you will need to some how use polymorphism ([you can read about it in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)).

If you think about it, after you assign the variable what would you do with it?

Lets assume `Employee` has method, `Foo` while `Department` has method `Bar`.

What would you do with the object returned from the query?

Will you attempt to call `instance.Foo()`? but what if it a `Department`?
So how about `instance.Bar()`? but what if it an `Employee`?

You need to call a method that you (and the compiler) know that exists in both classes.
This is where polymorphism kicks in.
You need to be able to refer to both in the same manner i.e. by the their common base class or by an interface they both Implement.

Of course, In .Net all object derives from the `object` class so you can always input them into an object list and than check for results. but IMHO this is not a very elegant solution.